# Reverse for 'AddCart' not found. 'AddCart' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I am Working on my project and I don't know how this error I got

Can anybody see what I'm missing?

This is my root project urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index),
    path('onlinePizza/', include('onlinePizza.urls')),
    path('cart/', include(('cart.urls'), namespace='cart')),
    path('accounts/', include(('accounts.urls'), namespace='accounts')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is my cart app urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from .import views
from cart.views import AddCart

app_name = 'cart'

urlpatterns = [
    path('add_cart/', views.AddCart, name='Cart'),
]
```

This is my cart app views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from cart.models import *

def AddCart(request):
    product = request.POST.get('product')
    remove = request.POST.get('remove')
    cart = request.session.get('cart')
    
    if not cart:
        request.session['cart'] = {}

    if cart:
        quantity=cart.get(product)
        if quantity:
            if remove:
                if quantity<=1:
                    cart.pop(product)
                else:
                    cart[product]=quantity-1
            else:   
                cart[product]=quantity+1
        else:
            cart[product]=1         
    else:
        cart={}
        cart[product]=1

    request.session['cart']=cart
    
    return redirect ('Menu')
```

This is my onlinePizza/pc_menu.html template

```html
<form action="{% url 'cart:AddCart' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
     <input hidden type="text" name="product" value="{{i.id}}">
     <button class="main-btn cart cart-btn" style="padding: 5px 32px">Add <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></button>
</form>
```

I try to solve this problem, but I show this error everywhere in my project.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! From what I can see, in the file `urls.py`, the `AddCart` view is registered under the name `Cart`. Try changing that name to `AddCart`. _(I'm not very familiar with Django, so I might be wrong)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need that `name`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('add_cart/', views.AddCart, name='Cart'),
]
```

and that link generator:

```
{% url 'cart:AddCart' %}
```

refering to the exactly same value. So it has to be either `'Cart'` and `'cart:Cart'` or `'AddCart'` and `'cart:AddCart'`.